# Problems with widget-overlay in jquery-ui 1.11.2; Overlay on top of dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem that the widget overlay goes on top of my dialog after upgrading from jquery-ui 1.8.16 to 1.11.2.

I'm able to fix the problem by adding z-index: 101 to the jquery.ui.dialog.css;

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 101;}
```

but have read that this isn't a good solutions. Ref. https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/, and that stacking with .ui-front / appendTo is the way to go. But I'm not able to get it working, as the widget-overlay also gets the class .ui-front.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
function getSelectedTabIndex() { return $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');}
$("#tabs").tabs('option', 'beforeActivate');
```

Anyone how knows a solutions, or a better way to do this?

Comment: Or is it a easy way to do the upgrade from 1.8.16 to 1.11.2 ? Like with jquery where you can use jquery-migrate?

Comment: What does your tabs code have to do with your dialog's z-index? ($tabs is undefined btw)